# Random Forest: Why does feature correlation not correspond to feature importance?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I generated a dataset with 15 features. Feature 9-15 are linearly dependant on feature 1-7 (I generated the data that way.)
This correlation plot proves this behaviour:

```
corr = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5',
                            'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10',
                            'F11', 'F12', 'F13', 'F14', 'F15']).corr()

sns.heatmap(corr)
```

[image]
    When I plot the feature importances from random forest clf I expect those highly correlating features to be of no importance. So this surprises me:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

feature_names = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5',
                 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10',
                 'F11', 'F12', 'F13', 'F14', 'F15']

importances = pd.DataFrame(clf.feature_importances_, index=feature_names,
                           columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)

importances.plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Why are feature 9-15 important afterall? What happens if I apply PCA to the data?

Comment: I won't decide the importance of the features based only on correlation. When we have correlated features in the data it could be possible that strong features end up with low scores.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. so then how do I pick the relevant features? These were the two criteria I was looking into...and it seems like they tell completely different stories

Comment: In your case it could be possible that the correlated measures are close to each other for the splitting hence they are showing up closer. That's the drawback of feature importance with random forest. Hence, you're seeing them in the result, Although, It's hard to say that without knowing what the features are.
why don't you drop correlated features based on your business rules or requirements and try after?

Comment: Initially I wanted to show that feeding a dataset with 15 features, of which 7 and 7 are correlating will leave me with 7 unimportant features after this analysis. But this does not seem to work now... Could you clarify what you mean by the "drawback of feature importance with random forest"?

Comment: "when the dataset has two (or more) correlated features, then from the point of view of the model, any of these correlated features can be used as the predictor, with no concrete preference of one over the others. But once one of them is used, the importance of others is significantly reduced since effectively the impurity they can remove is already removed by the first feature. As a consequence, they will have a lower reported importance". You can refer this article http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/

Comment: 1) not a *programming* question - better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 2) question has actually nothing to do with `pandas` or `seaborn`, kindly do not spam the tags (removed)